# Regex - How can I take everything between the second and third comma?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

`"4w4190,UK,value,,another data,,job,1,,23"`

I want to remove everything before the second comma and everything after the third comma.
The result should look like this:

`'value'`

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: This is presumably CSV. Use PHP's CSV functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this task, using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will do the job, e.g.

```php
$myArray = explode(",", "4w4190,UK,value,,another data,,job,1,,23");
var_export($myArray);
```

Returns

```
array (
  0 => '4w4190',
  1 => 'UK',
  2 => 'value',
  3 => '',
  4 => 'another data',
  5 => '',
  6 => 'job',
  7 => '1',
  8 => '',
  9 => '23',
)
```

Where index 2 contains your value (`$myArray[2]`).